# Batch Script Input Problems

Tags: if-statement, input, batch-file

I have two questions regarding a batch script I'm working on. I realize that batch script questions are common but haven't found an answer to my exact question so I thought I'd try asking. The problematic areas are the user input sections on the menus.

There are two problems: 1) Input entered that is not one of the specified choices will cause the script to jump to random areas. And 2) some sections that use external programs are not taking the user %input% even when I know the syntax and flag use would normally be correct (as in, I can run them manually... so for some reason the input isn't capturing on them).

First issue example:

```
:MenuOne
echo Select one of the following options:
echo 1) x
echo 2) y
echo Q) Quit

set INPUT=
set /P INPUT=[1,2,Q]: %=%
If "%INPUT%"=="1" goto xoption
If "%INPUT%"=="2" goto yoption
If /I "%INPUT%"=="Q" goto Quit

:xoption
@REM Here goes a lot more submenus and/or options that actually run tools via cmd.

:yoption
@REM Again, menus and/or tools being invoked, in a listed menu, designed like above.

:Quit
echo Quitting...
exit
```

If a user types "b" at the selection prompt, I would love for the script to give an error and repeat the menu. Instead it jerks around other menus. I'm guessing that I need some ELSE statements? Does anyone have an example that I can use to accomplish this?

Second issue of *some* commands not using the %input% properly and returning an error as though it never received the %input%.

```
set /P INPUT=[Testone Input]: %testone%
set /P INPUT=[Testtwo Input]: %testtwo%
commandtorun.exe -f %testone% -h %testtwo%
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to use `choice` (http://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) because it will persist until you set the correct input

```
CHOICE /C XYQ /M "Select of the following options [X,Y,Q]"
if errorlevel 1 goto :x
if errorlevel 2 goto :y
uf errorlevel 3 goto :q
```

Yet it's still possible to be done with IFs

```
set INPUT=
set /P INPUT=[1,2,Q]: %=%
If "%INPUT%"=="1" goto xoption
If "%INPUT%"=="2" goto yoption
If /I "%INPUT%"=="Q" goto Quit
rem -- will be executed only if the all the above are not true
goto :eof
```

For the second problem..You are not using `SET /P` correctly (the name of the variable should be in the front) , or you are trying something that I don't understand (where input variable is used):

```
set /P testone=[Testone Input]:
set /P testtwo=[Testtwo Input]:
commandtorun.exe -f %testone% -h %testtwo%
```

Comment: Note: if OP is using Windows XP, `choice` is not available by default.

Comment: Awesome answer - I can't believe I was using the set /P wrong. You're right, I was essentially overwriting the old input I think by not using two different variables. Works now, much appreciated! Edit: right as michaelb958 said it, I tried it. Oh well, back to set /P works just fine now :) thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your program as written, all your choices will fall through to the next one.  If no relevant choice is entered, it will run `:xoption` and `:yoption`.  Each of those should probably return to the menu after executing:

```
:MenuOne
echo Select one of the following options:
echo 1) x
echo 2) y
echo Q) Quit

set INPUT=
set /P INPUT=[1,2,Q]: %=%
If "%INPUT%"=="1" goto xoption
If "%INPUT%"=="2" goto yoption
If /I "%INPUT%"=="Q" goto Quit

echo Invalid selection.
echo.
goto MenuOne

:xoption
@REM Here goes a lot more submenus and/or options that actually run tools via cmd.
goto MenuOne

:yoption
@REM Again, menus and/or tools being invoked, in a listed menu, designed like above.
goto MenuOne
```

A real simple way to ensure a valid selection is made is to use the `choice` command instead of `set /P`.  That will force the user to enter a value:

```
choice -c 12Q
echo %errorlevel%
```

The `choice` command will return the index of the selected character (1, 2 or 3 in the above example).  A bonus is that it is case-insensitive, so you don't have to worry about checking both `Q` and `q`.

Comment: Thank you! As it turns out choice isn't available to me. But everything else you suggested worked. Much appreciated.